# Align GridView.count() with something like MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following GridView.count() that have 2 widgets:

[image: Current GridView.count()]

What I want is:

[image]

I'm making a custom Widget of buttons that has N buttons and when I have a blank space left, I want to space the buttons evenly or just add the space between them. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with ListView[Row..] on this case, If you like to use GridView, the children will be ratio depend on size and  you need wrap with another widget to align it.

```dart
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: List.generate(
    4,
    (index) => Align(
      alignment: index.isEven? Alignment.centerLeft:Alignment.centerRight,
      child: ,
    ),
  ),
),
```

But this will be better with row

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 4,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this :
**mainAxisSpacing: 10,**
In your gridView widget